# Is dual audio output possible?

Tags: audio, sound-card, audio-output

I have integrated audio card that supports 5.1 audio, it has 6 I/O plugins in back and 2 at front. My card name is "Realtek High Definition Audio card".

So my question is: Is it possible to set up more audio controllers? For example: My audio player outputs sound to one audio jack (my sound system), and for example web browser or game outputs sound do my headphones ? Is there any driver or soft that allows this. OS:XP , but I can change if some other OS supports it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) allows you to split different audio streams from different applications to different outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I believe Realtek allows you to separate the front audio and rear audio jacks in their control panel into two visible devices. From there, you simply have to tell Windows which device to send the audio to. Most audio-specific things (games, teamspeak, skype, ventrillo, mumble, etc.) allow you to specify the output device; set your speakers as the system default, and then set applications you want to use your headphones with to use the front audio, and plug your headphones in there.